# Unique data in each VU thread in k6 / shared state between VUs

Tags: javascript, performance, load-testing, stress-testing, k6

Is it possible to get a global counter shared across VU threads in k6? e.g. for user registration where email address must be unique, I'm using `"user" + i + "@example.com"` ...

Currently using a global variable:

```
let i = 1
```

in global namespace. Single-VU works properly, but 2 VUs cause 50% of requests to fail, etc. I'm assuming each VU runs its own JS. Is there a reference to the thread (goroutine?) number/id available to the JS runtime?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the numeric counters `__VU` and `__ITER`.

`__VU`: This value is assigned incrementally for each new VU. If the VU gets terminated (e.g. as part of a ramp-down operation) and the test coordinator launches the same VU again, the VU will have the same previous value.

`__ITER`: The current iteration number for a given VU.